# I want to print the variable I get on the form in the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var roomPrice = 12;


// bootstrap datepicker configuration 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#from").datepicker({

    changeMonth: false,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    startDate: "-Infinty",
    endDate: "+Infinty",
    language: "en",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  });
  $(" #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+0w",
    changeMonth: false,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: "-Infinty",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    language: "en",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  });
});

function ChooseContact(data) {
  var totalrooms = data.value;
  document.getElementById("totalrooms").value = (Number(totalrooms));
  //CheckItemRent("adet");
}


function calculateDuration() {
  var diff = 0;
  if (startDate != "" && endDate != "") {
    var startDate = new Date($('#from').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#to').val());
    diff = endDate - startDate;
  }

  if (diff == 0) {
    $("#totaldays").val("1");
    $("#totaldays2").html("1");
    $("#grandtotal").val("").css("color", "black");
    $("#grandtotal2").html("").css("float", "left");
    $("#grandtotal3").html("&nbsp;TL").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#grandtotal4").html('<button type="submit" form="my_form"  class="float-right  btn btn-sm btn-default shadow btn-rounded"> ' + $("#grandtotal") + ' TLRent <i class="material-icons md-18">shopping_cart</i></button>');


  }
  if (diff > 1) {
    $("#totaldays").val((diff / 86400000) + 1);
    $("#totaldays2").html((diff / 86400000) + 1 + "&nbsp; Gün  Kiralama Günü");
    $("#grandtotal").val("").css("color", "black");
    $("#grandtotal2").html("").css("float", "left");
    $("#grandtotal3").html("&nbsp;TL").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#grandtotal4").html('<button type="submit" form="my_form" class="float-right  btn btn-sm btn-default shadow btn-rounded"> ' + $("#grandtotal") + ' TL Rent <i class="material-icons md-18">shopping_cart</i></button>');




  }
  if (diff < 0) {
    $("#totaldays").val((diff / 86400000) - 1);
    $("#totaldays2").val((diff / 86400000) - 1);
    $("#grandtotal").val("Error in dates...").css("color", "red");
    $("#grandtotal2").html("");
    $("#grandtotal3").html("");
    $("#grandtotal4").html("");
  }
  return;
}



function grandTotal() {
  calculateDuration();
  var days = $("#totaldays").val();
  var rooms = $("#totalrooms").val();

  if (days != "" && parseInt(days) > 0) {
    if (rooms != "") {
      var total = parseInt(days) * parseInt(rooms) * roomPrice;
      $("#grandtotal").val(total.toFixed(0)).css("color", "red");
      $("#grandtotal2").html(total.toFixed(0));
    } else {
      $("#grandtotal").val("").css("color", "black");
      $("#grandtotal2").html("");
    }
  }
}



$("#rooms, #from, #to").on("change", function() {
  grandTotal();
  $(".datepicker").hide();
  CheckItemRent("adet");

});


  $("#grandtotal4").html('<button type="submit" form="my_form"  class="float-right  btn btn-sm btn-default shadow btn-rounded"> ' + $("#grandtotal") + ' TLRent <i class="material-icons md-18">shopping_cart</i></button>');
```

hello guys
I want to print this taga variable but it doesn't work.
the values I get from the javascript calculator
I can print it as div id
but i can't print it in the following tag
what do you think is the problem?

```
' + grandtotal+ ' 
 ' + $("#grandtotal")val() '
```

```js
$("#grandtotal4").html('<button type="submit" form="my_form"  class="float-right  btn btn-sm btn-default shadow btn-rounded"> ' + $("#grandtotal") + ' TLRent <i class="material-icons md-18">shopping_cart</i></button>');
```

I tried these, but it didn't work.
how to print into grandtotal4 variable.
my main target
When div appears, I want to show the total price above the button.

Comment: `$("#grandtotal")` should be `$("#grandtotal").val()`

Comment: <button type="submit" form="my_form"  class="float-right  btn btn-sm btn-default shadow btn-rounded"> '+ $("#grandtotal").val() +' TLRent <i class="material-icons md-18">shopping_cart</i></button> I did not try this way, it did not work.